# issues with jquery select2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

i am working on select2 for the first time i am trying to use multiple select2 but its not working kindly look at my code

```js
         $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#e1").select2();
         });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="e1" style="width:300px" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
  <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
  <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please check if you are getting any error in console.

Comment: I have edited your quesion and nothing seems wrong.

Comment: Script tag is not closed

Comment: @PunitGajjar yes on console its showing select2() is not a function

Comment: make sure JS are included properly

Comment: @Manu its a typo here otherwise its closed in my code

Comment: @PunitGajjar i dont think there is an issue with including the js file i have double checked the path

Comment: what is this  $("#e1").select2(); ? directly you can call select2() inside ready function, bcoz $("#e1") refers to select itself.

Comment: @TalhaSarwar i have created a snippet , created a fiddle and posted me entire HTML code, Please check it .

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
                    $("#e1").select2();
                });
```

```html
<html>
    <head>        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css">

    </head>

    <body>
        <select id="e1" style="width:300px" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
            <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
            <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Might Problem with the `JS` you have included or with the version , 
check the fiddle i have created.

https://jsfiddle.net/rev8vkcr/

check my HTML code.

```
<html>
    <head>        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css">

        <script type='text/javascript'>
                $(document).ready(function() { 
                    $("#e1").select2();
                });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <select id="e1" style="width:300px" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
            <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
            <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @TalhaSarwar , what was the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that either you have not loaded jQuery, or some other script has taken control of the global $. No relation to select2

This should be your folder structre as per your code.
[image: This should be your folder structre]

> the dist folder must conain two folders js and css
>
> js folder should contain select2.min.js
>
> css folder should contain select2.min.css
>
> the outside js folder must contain jQuery.js

here myhtml.html code be like

```
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/select2.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function(){
      $("#e1").select2();    
      });
    </script>

    <style>
      body {
        padding: 40px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

 <body>
    <select id="e1" style="width: 300px" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
        <option value="CA">California</option>
        <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
        <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
        <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
        <option value="MT">Montana</option>
        <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
        <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
        <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
        <option value="UT">Utah</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @TalhaSarwar What was the issue??